# Dismiss a tabbar over Navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to figure out how to properly create a login screen which will be presented in case the user's session is expired.
So my initial controller is a navigation controller for login/sign up. 
In case the user's session is not expired then I am initializing a tabbar with a another navigation controller inside of it:

```
if(![userID isEqualToString:@""] && ![userID isEqualToString:@"0"] && userID!=nil){
    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toLoginVC" sender:self];

    self.navigationController.view.alpha=0;
    self.view.alpha=0;


    UIStoryboard *sc =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];

     UITabBarController *vc = [sc instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];

     vc.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

This works fine. My question is what happens to the first navigation controller? Can I dismiss the tabbar in case the user's session is expired? Should I initiate again the login view controller?

PS. I tried

```
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

and I am getting: Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller  while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!

Comment: Where have you put these codes? In your AppDelegate or somewhere else?

Comment: I mean, its just a modal view you are presenting. What does this have to do with a navigation controller?

Comment: My initial controller is the loginVC which is inside a navigation controller.If the user is logged in then I am initializing the tabbar which also have a navigation controller inside of it.